# nginx not load css js with reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

[this is the error tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmbGW.png)

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://lb.domain.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://lb.domain.com/media/css/843a626f40872c37930850e56f8a3215.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
my nginx config file is:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name lb.domain.com;

ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl/domain.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl/domain.com.key;

ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;

ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

location / {
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
proxy_pass http://domain;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

and I use many ways could't solve this question.

can anyone helps?

thanks!

Comment: You should re-check your code, does anywhere request http:// instead of https:// resources? as I understand, your nginx configuration declares an HTTPS server, receives and passes requests to an HTTP server. So if your code request an HTTP resource, nginx won't change to HTTPS for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping I could send this as a comment, but I cannot figure out how. Did you refresh the Nginx service? It should be

```
Sudo nginx.service restart
```